# FindWindow fails

Tags: python, pywin32

I've troubles with `FindWindow` using `pywin32` extension.
Simple C code:

```
int main()
{
  HWND h = FindWindow(NULL, TEXT("SomeApp"));
  if (h != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
      SetForegroundWindow(h);
  return 0;
}
```

Works well. Same with python:

```
import win32gui

h = win32gui.FindWindow(None, "SomeApp")
if h:
    win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(h)
else:
    print "SomeApp not found"
```

Fails, SomeApp not found. I suggest text encoding may be cause trouble here but not found any information in docs how to specify text.

**Update:**
I've tested code on other machine and don't see any troubles. So, configuration on my first machine should be incorrect. I've update my investigation results if found the problem.

Comment: Do you run your code in IDLE, because I just tried similar code with windows calc, and it's not working in IDLE but directly in python shell in command line.

Comment: It's called `SetForegroundWindow` in python too. The first character is uppercase

Comment: I just typo in setForeground function. In my full listing i've else statement. And i don't use IDLE, run script from cmd.exe. Thanks for feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the C code, you are checking `h != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`, in Python `h != None`. `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` is not `0`/`null`/`None`.

Python defines `win32file.INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` via the `win32file` import.

Also, instead of printing "SomeApp not found", you can do something like:

```
gle = win32api.GetLastError()
err = win32api.FormatMessage(gle)[:-2]
print 'SomeApp not found: LastError=%d - %s' % (gle, err)
```

This should give you more details on the failure if `FindWindow` has legitimately failed for some reason (or "Success" if it worked).

Comment: Agreed, it looking more corretly but FindWindow returns PyHandle object which have __non_zero__ method.

Comment: I really don't know where were troubles. After full reinstallation python (2.7) and pywin32 it works so question is solved. I've checked as accept answer because no other answers.